# Upgrade Outlook 2003/07/10/13 addin to be used for Click-to-Run (C2R)

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office, vsto, add-in

I have an addin that is compatible with Outlook 2003 - 2013 by using the various versions of VSTO.

It seems that the majority of small businesses will have the Click To Release version, which is not compatible with addins.

Is there a way to make an addin compatible with 2013 C2R, or does it need to be rewritten to be an "App" using Napa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C2R Office  installation load COM addins in exactly the same way as the regular version of the Office, there is nothing you need to do.

What is the exact problem that you are running into?

Comment: There was no problem except most web articles say add-ins don't work and MSDN do not do a C2R version for testing. In the end, we signed up for Office365 trial and found the add-in did work fine!